# Emacs C++ mode creates trailing space+backslash after preprocessor statements

Tags: c++, emacs

Over the last year I've tried to use Emacs 24.4/24.5 several times for writing C++ code. However, every time I ran into a very basic issue with preprocessor statements: When I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on a line with a preprocessor statement, Emacs inserts weird trailing whitespace and a trailing `\`. Typically, the indentation in the next line is wrong, and furthermore, the behavior continues in this line. So pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> three times after a `#include <iostream>` would for instance result in:

```
#include <iostream>                             \
                                                \
                                                \
  | <- this is where the cursor is now (at indentation 2)
```

To clarify: each line is filled up with whitespace and has a trailing `\`.

Similarly if I place the cursor at the beginning of the `#include` line and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, I get an ugly space+slash line above.

My <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key (`RET` in Emacs terminology) is bound to `(autopair-newline)`.

How can I get rid of this behavior? I basically want Emacs not to do anything fancy here, just a plain "new line". Note that I don't want to revert `RET` back to a completely plain "new line" in general (e.g., I would like to keep automatic indentation in other cases). Therefore, I wondering what could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem. In the [CC mode documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Getting-Started.html#Getting-Started) there is an example of binding <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in a way that it performs a newline+indent. Actually I already got the newline+indent behavior, because I bind `RET` to `'comment-indent-new-line` in general. But apparently `'comment-indent-new-line` does not play nicely with CC mode. I have now added this to my `init.el`, which simply overwrites the binding in a `c-initialization-hook`:

```lisp
(defun my-make-CR-do-indent ()
  (define-key c-mode-base-map "\C-m" 'c-context-line-break))
(add-hook 'c-initialization-hook 'my-make-CR-do-indent)
```